# Menu not showing in Spinner

Tags: android, kotlin, drop-down-menu, spinner

I am trying to make a simple menu for genders but nothing shows on my screen except a little drop down icon. Here is my code:

```
<Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gender"/>


var gender = view.findViewById(R.id.gender) as Spinner
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity!!.applicationContext, R.array.genders, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
                .also {adapter ->
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                    gender.adapter = adapter
                }
<string-array name="genders">
        <item>Mr.</item>
        <item>Ms.</item>
        <item>other</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: `activity!!.applicationContext` – Do not use the application `Context` there. It won't have the appropriate theme. Use the `Activity`.

Comment: use the property android:entries="@array/genders"

Comment: @ZahoorSaleem thanks, now it is showing the options